# Programmatically close Material-UI Autocomplete popper results

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

ReactJS/Material-UI newbie question. I'm making use of Material-UI Autocomplete and am trying to create a function that I can programmatically call to close the Material-UI autocomplete popper results list but struggling on how to do so. So far I've added a ref to the autocomplete field and tried to trigger a blur since the popper already automatically closes onBlur but regrettably I get an error message stating onBlur isn't a function. Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

```
const closePopper = () => {    
    myAutocompleteFieldRef.current.onBlur();
  };
```

Comment: Why do you need to programmatically close it?

Comment: Because it is using Google Places and I injected a custom "Current Location" option to the options list which when clicked calls a function to get user's current location using native browser "navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition" and when this occurs it leaves the autocomplete options list open. I need to programmatically close it after this occurs, in the same manner that Yelp does so https://www.yelp.com/

Answer (score 5):

Switch to implementing AutoComplete element in controlled mode.

You can create state in your component for controlling the open prop of Autocomplete component.
The forward a function which updates the state down to your custom option.

For example,

```
export default function CustomAutoComplete() {
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
  const closePopper = () => setOpen(false);
  const openPopper = () => setOpen(true);
  return (
    <Autocomplete
      id="controlled-open-sample"
      open={open}
      onOpen={openPopper}
      onClose={closePopper}
      renderOption={opt => <CustomLocationOption {...opt} afterSelect={closePopper} />}
       /* ... */
       />}
    />
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately, I tried this by simply calling the closePopper() function via Autocomplete onChange and onInputChange and popper doesn't close.

Comment: I don't think the value is changed if popper is opened. You can share your updated MCVE and I can give it another look.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to accomplish this by making use of the [popper "anchorEL"](https://material-ui.com/components/popper/)

Comment: could you elaborate? How did you configure the anchorEl?